# How can I intercept the text property on a control inherited form a WPF TextBox?

Tags: wpf, textbox, dependency-properties

What I want to do is intercept assignments to the Text property on my control inherited from a TextBox. I the want to modify this text and have the modified text shown in the text box.  I aslo need the ability to return something different from what is shown in the text box when the property is read. In Win Forms I could do this by overriding the Text property as it was declared virtual. Obviously things are a bit different with dependency properties. One idea I had was to use OverridePropertyMetadata to have my own callback detect the property change and then call the original callback obtained with GetMetadata. This doesn’t work as property changed callbacks are merged.  I’d be interested if there is another way to do it which is specific to this property but I like to find out if it is possible “override” dependency properties in general.

My application is a formatted text box when the text is set to 1000 say (for a numeric format), the text box shows 1,000 but when you read the text you get back 1000 again- the box will keep track of the un formatted text internally. I managed to implement in Win Forms fairly easily but am now trying to port it to WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I think `OverridePropertyMetadata` is the way to go, but rather than defining a new `PropertyChangedCallback`, you could write a new `CorceValueCallback`:

```
static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    string s = (string)baseValue;

    // Change s to whatever you want
    ...

    return s;
}
```

Comment: I looked at some more examples and came across this idea which works for when the property is written but I also want to override the value that is returned when it is read. I will update my question to be clearer. I'm not sure whether this is possible - the example I looked at was a masked text box - when the text property is read you get the value including the mask. Maybe the best I can do is to introduce another property.